# deploy asp.net class with variables

Tags: asp.net

I have one quesion, let's put I have a project with 3 web forms and each form has inside 5 connection strings or any other static variable so total would be 15.

And let's assume that I can't deploy the dll because I am told to use aspx.cs and aspx files only.

If I don't want neither store the connection string inside the web.config I can create a normal class  (no aspx.cs only class.cs) where I create a static Constant for using it in my classes.

In the end I have 3 aspx.cs files, 3 aspx and one cs, but if in the IDE it works when I deploy it says "couldn't find reference to Class."

Why is that? It would be very useful for storing variables.

Comment: Would you reconsider not storing the connection strings in web.config? If they change and you have them hard-coded then you have to recompile the application. If you are concerned that they can be read as plain text in the web.config file, you can encrypt the appropriate section: [Walkthrough: Encrypting Configuration Information Using Protected Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky%28v=vs.140%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you deploy using the Web Site project model, the class files (.cs) need to be placed in a special folder called `App_Code`.

Comment: Web Application projects must be compiled into a DLL.

Comment: Actually, the code behind (.cs) files don't need to be in the App_Code directory, but all other .cs files do.

Comment: @NightOwl888  That's what I meant, aspx.cs files go in the web root and .cs files go in `App_Code`

Answer (score 1):

There are two ASP.NET project types:

- Web Application Projects: Here, the code in aspx.cs and .cs files is compiled into a DLL. If you cannot deploy the DLL, you cannot use this project type.
- Web Site Projects: That seems to be what you are looking for. The code is compiled at run time; you just need to make sure that your shared code (your .cs file) is located in the [App_Code folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23(v=vs.140).aspx).

If you project is currently a web application project, you need to change it to a web site project or change the opinion of the person who told you not to use DLLs.